# Ruby on Rails - How to use a select box to change an attribute of the selected items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html-select

I'll start off with a bit of context to my question.  I have a group of offices which each have reviewers associated with them.  A reviewer can only be associated with one office.  I want to create two select boxes.  One lists all of the reviewers that are associated with the office I am viewing, the other lists all of the reviewers that are available (which is basically all of the reviewers that aren't already assigned to this office).

The goal of the current reviewer's listbox is to set their office to nil when they are selected.  The goal of the available reviewers listbox is to set their office to this office's id when they are selected. I'm not sure how to change only the reviewers' office_id when using a select box.

Code-wise, what I have so far is this:

**office_controller.rb**

```
def edit
  @office = Group.find params[:id] if params[:id]
  @current_reviewers = Reviewer.find_all_by_group_id(@office.id)
  @available_reviewers = Reviewer.where('group_id <> ?',[@office.id])
end

def update
  ?
end
```

**office/edit.html.erb**

```
<% form_for(@office, :url => {:controller => :office, :action => :update, :id => @office.id}, :html => {}) do  |f| %>
  ...
  <%= select_tag 'removedReviewers', options_from_collection_for_select(@current_reviewers, "id", "display_name"), :multiple => true %>
  <%= select_tag 'chosenReviewers', options_from_collection_for_select(@available_reviewers, "id", "display_name"), :multiple => true %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the ability to get a select_tag to get the selected objects as a collection via the [] modifier of the select_tag name.  So, in this example it was:

```
<%= select_tag 'removedReviewers[]', options_from_collection_for_select(@current_reviewers,    "id", "display_name"), :multiple => true %>
```

And for the controller code to handle it, I did this:

```
@removedReviewers = params[:removedReviewers]

if !@removedReviewers.nil?
  @removedReviewers.each do |reviewer|
    @reviewer = Reviewer.find(reviewer)
    @reviewer.group_id = nil
    @reviewer.save
  end
end
```

And the equivalent for the chosen/available reviewers.